# Publishing a WCF service using web deployment failed on Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, webdeploy

I am trying to publish a WCF service to IIS in Windows 8 using Web deploy. The publish process is failing with the following error:

Web Deployment task failed. There was an error reading IIS configuration schema from 'C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\schema

Yes, I am running VS2010 in admin mode.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need to create/configure the website/apppool on the remote server, or just deploy the content/binaries?

Comment: create/configure the website/appool. Thanks Richard.

Comment: What version of msdeploy is running on the server/client? Also are you using publish profiles (pubxml) via the azure SDK or are you using the VS2010 RTM publishing stuff?

Comment: I am using the VS2010 RTM  publishing stuff.

Comment: MSDeploy should be running in the server/client (it is all in the same dev machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue when using WS2012 with Windows 8 and IIS 8

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2735834/en-us?fr=1

I`m migrating to VS2012, let`s see if this really solves the issue.